# JQ select works on command line but does not when ran inside a bash script

Tags: jq

I am doing a curl call and piping the output to jq to filter out the value of a field if the value of another field matches my pattern using jq select.

the json looks like {"id":"12345","name":"myname"}

```
NAME=$(output of another command which will be the same as that of the name value in the JSON above)    
    
ID=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:<token>" "<api_endpoint>" | jq -r --arg NAMES "$NAME" '.[] | select(.name==$NAMES) | .id')
echo ID="$ID"
```

No matter what I try, the ID variable is null. If I take the curl command and run it on the command line it works as expected.

Comment: Is the JSON object in the Q exactly the same as the curl output?  If so, the jq query is wrong; if not, please show a sample (or an illustrative synopsis of a sample) of the curl result.  Also, what exactly is $NAME?  Is it `myname` or `"myname"`?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you run the curl command and redirect the output to a file, then try to reproduce the problem with the contents of that file. If it's large or contains sensitive data, reduce or censor it while still reproducing the problem. Then show us the file, a complete bash script that demonstrates the problem, and both the expected and actual output. As it stands your query doesn't match your data, it's not clear if the echo command is inside your script, and it's not clear how you're running the script or what you see going wrong.

Comment: To expand upon what both peak and Weeble are saying, please read up on [how to create reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to post as part of your question. Not only will it help you get an answer, I often find that the exercise of reducing my example uncovers the issue.

Comment: Try running your script with the `-x` flag, it should show you which commands are executed

Answer (score 0):

The `.[]` filter will turn `{"id":"123","name":"myname"}` into `123\nmyname`, effectively returning only the values. IOW, `.id` and `.name` are no longer available. Therefore, I doubt that your script works in an interactive shell, unless your given input is not the real input.

- Input: `{"id":"12345","name":"myname"}`
- Filter: `.[]`
- (Raw) Output:

  ```
  12345
  myname
  ```

Use without `.[]` and apply `select` to your object directly:

- Filter: `select(.name=="myname") | .id`
- (Raw) Output: `12345`